# Is there an R #Rstats package for managing the GPIO pins?

Tags: gpio

Julia has it:  https://github.com/JuliaBerry/PiGPIO.jl

Does R have a package, e.g. library(RPiGpio)

Keywords for search: statistics data science

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking out the [rPython](http://rpython.r-forge.r-project.org) package. It will allow you to make calls to Python code and functions within R. Therefore, you should then be able to use one of the many Python GPIO libraries with your R code.